# React statics with ES6 classes

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Does the statics object work with ES6 classes in React?

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    // ...
  }

}

React.statics = {
  someMethod: function() {
    //...
  }
};
```

Something like the above gives me undefined method `someMethod` when I do `SomeComponent.someMethod()`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`statics` only works with `React.createClass`. Simply declare the method as a static class method:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

  static someMethod() {
    //...
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }

}
```

---

Regarding

```
React.statics = { ... }
```

You are literally creating a `statics` property on the `React` object. That property does not *magically* extend your component.

Comment: Note that static properties (e.g. `static propTypes = {...}`) are supported by babel and the jsx tools; but are only an ES7 proposal.  Static methods are ES6.

Comment: doing it like this I always get `Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null` error while the same methods without static modifier works properly. I'm not using any class variables in my methods...

Answer (score 24):

Although `statics` only works for `React.createClass`, you can still write static methods in ES6 notation. If you are using ES7, then you can also write static properties.

You can write statics inside ES6+ classes this way:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
    ...
    }

    static someMethod(){
    }
}
```

Or outside the class like this:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
   ....
}

Component.propTypes = {...}
Component.someMethod = function(){....}
```

If you want to write it like the former, then you have to set `stage: 0` on Babel (since its experimental).

Comment: Notice that `propTypes = …` is not ES6 notation.

Comment: You're correct, this seems to be ES7 Property Initializer notation. http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#es7-property-initializers

Comment: In order to use ES7 you have to `npm install babel-preset-stage-0` and then add `"stage-0"` to .babelrc like so: `{"presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]}`

Answer (score 1):

**Statics can be accessed without having to instantiate a component.** Normally they aren't that useful but there are a few special cases. For example into routing when you leave the current page with doing a ACTION PERFORM  then through Statics methods you can hold/ASKED the user whether he really want to leave the page.
For example:

```
exampleComponent= React.createClass({
statics:{
        willTransitionFrom: function(transition,component){
            // check any state here or value Aasked the user.
        }
    }
});
```

**It exposes willTransitionTo and willTransitionFrom lifecycle methods**. both are particular is useful as a static as you can actually cancel a transition before instantiating a component.

Answer (score 0):

Stop. Just declare a class without extending React.Component and it will works.

```
class YourStaticClass {

   static YourMethod(){

   }

}
export default YourStaticClass;
```

in the other classes,
You can simply import your class and trigger the function

```
import YourStaticClass from "whatever";

...
YourStaticClass.YourMethod();
...
```

Comment: Is it possible to import just the static method inside that class by something like this? `import {YourMethod} from "whatever";`? Is there any way?

Answer (score -6):

`statics` works only for React components, [check docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#statics).

Comment: Doesn't the OP have a react component?

Comment: That's exactly your answer. What's OP?

Comment: "OP" refers either to the question or to the person who wrote the question. Maybe you just phrased it a bit strangely, because the this is definitely a React component. It's not created with `React.createClass`.