# childContextTypes in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How would you write the object childContextTypes in ES6?

```
var A = React.createClass({

    childContextTypes: {
         name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    },

    getChildContext: function() {
         return { name: "Jonas" };
    },

    render: function() {
         return <B />;
    }
});
```

Comment: You wouldn't at all. `class`es don't support static members. Assign it explicitly after the declaration, or use `Object.assign`

Comment: Uh my friend I need a little more help. Can you show me?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29433130/1048572) help? Not sure if it's a duplicate

Comment: You are right; static properties is is for ES. If I assign it explicitly after, then it compiles fine(I am using Babel). Thanks man, I have recognised this a "useful comment".

Comment: You should also add your final solution as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 22):

Since you are using Babel anyway, you can use `static` (ES7) in your code like this:

```
export default class A extends React.Component {

  static childContextTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.string,
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return { name: "Jonas" }
  }

  render() {
    return <B />
  }
}
```

More info: [React on ES6+](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus)

Comment: The more-info blog page has moved to https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus

Comment: Thank you jakewins. Updated the link accordingly.

Answer (score 14):

The issue is that `childContextTypes` needs to be defined on the "class", which is what `static` does. So these two solutions seem to work:

```
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);

    this.constructor.childContextTypes = {
      name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    };
  }
}
```

Or

```
class A extends React.Component {

}

A.childContextTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to move "childContextTypes" out of the class:

> class {
> .,,
> };
>
> childContextTypes() {..}

Or wait for ES7 to have static properties.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class Grandparent extends React.Component {
  static childContextTypes = {
    getUser: PropTypes.func
  };

   getChildContext() {
    return {
      getUser: () => ({ name: 'Bob' })
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <Parent />;
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component  {
  render() {
    return <Child />;
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    getUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const user = this.context.getUser();
    return <p>Hello {user.name}!</p>;
  }
}
```

Source code form here:
[React ES6 Context](http://jaysoo.ca/2015/06/09/react-contexts-and-dependency-injection/)

Comment: There is a syntax error at `getUser: () => ({ name: 'Bob' })`

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Coffeescript...

change

```
childContextTypes:
```

to

```
@childContextTypes:
```