# jsdocs3 error 'Unexpected token ='

Tags: reactjs, jsdoc3

i always get this error message within my React JSX files:

```
export default class applicationContainer extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        params: React.PropTypes.any,
        route: React.PropTypes.any
    };
    ....
```

or

```
componentDidMount = () => {
      ...}
```

any ideas.

Thx

Timo

Comment: to make it clear: jsdoc3 makes trouble, the rest is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct syntax should be:

```
export default class applicationContainer extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // ...
    }
};

applicationContainer.propTypes = {
    params: React.PropTypes.any,
    route: React.PropTypes.any
};
```

Comment: nope, its not a wrong syntax, just look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433130/react-statics-with-es6-classes